# Mailgun router filter check if attachment exist

Tags: email, filter, mime, mailgun

I want to setup a filter in mailgun route to detect if an attachment is present. The [documentation](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#receiving-forwarding-and-storing-messages) says it can filter based on MIME headers. I've tried the following options, but none have worked. Any ideas?

```
match_header("Content-Type", "multipart.*")
match_header("attachment-count", ".*")
match_header("attachment-0", ".*")
```

Comment: Did you finally find out the answer?

Comment: @Chris: no I did not. The workaround I did was make a single endpoint on my server that accepts multiple Content-types, and let my server handle the switching logic.

Answer (score 2):

Both POSTs were of type multipart. 
One is multipart/alternative (no attachments) and the other multipart/mixed (with attachments)

I was able to detect incoming mail with attachment(s) with the following match_header definition:

```
match_header("Content-Type", "^multipart/mixed(.*)$")
```

Your two other attempts:

```
match_header("attachment-count", ".*")
match_header("attachment-0", ".*")
```

may work if you use this instead:

```
match_header("attachment-count", "^(.*)$")
match_header("attachment-0", "^(.*)$")
```